# Push existing git repo to github: system cannot make a pull

Tags: git, github

I have a local repo using git. Now I want to push it to my github repo. 
I follow the online instruction as to add remote repo inside the web directory:

> git remote add  github git@github.com:[username]/[repo_name].git

After that I make a push (**git push -u github master**), the terminal response suggest I make a pull to avoid non-fast-forward.

Then I try to make a pull: 
(first try)

> git pull -u github master 
>   (second try)
>   git pull github master

Both return **fatal: Uh oh. Your system reports no Git commands at all.**

I already check .git/config file, the remote git is already there. Why git can make a push but not a pull.

My .git/config file is:

```
[remote "github"]
        url = git@github.com:[username]/[repo_name].git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

Comment: do you have a repo of that name on github?

Comment: what is the `-u` supposed to do in the 2nd command (`git pull`)?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure this isn't a path issue, as explained in [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/14008) (for windows, but valid for other OS too).
Check also if you don't have any active `git alias` which might prevent a `git pull` to work properly.

---

Regarding the path issue, the [OP aladine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306103/aladine) confirms in the comments:

> I discover that after I reinstall git, it works as normal.

Comment: Thanks, I discover that after I reinstall git, it works as normal.

Comment: @aladine Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.